# Python class members different from instance members

Tags: python, checkbox, directory, attributes, wxpython

I'm trying to get the value of WxPython checkboxes. When I run the following command inside my Class:

```
print(self)
a = dir(self)
print(a)

#result
<__main__.Window object at 0x03B02670>
['AcceleratorTable', 'AcceptsFocus', etc...
 'm_staticText3', 'm_staticText31', 'm_staticText311', 'm_staticText3111', 'm_staticText3112', 'm_staticText31121', 'm_staticline1', 'm_staticline3']
```

My checkboxes are part of the returned result. But when I substitute the 'self' for the class 'Window', the checkbox attributes are missing!

```
print(Window)
a = dir(Window)
print(a)

#result
<class '__main__.Window'>
['AcceleratorTable', 'AcceptsFocus', etc..,
 'WindowVariant', '__bool__', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

It looks the same, but my checkboxes are not returned! What's going on here?

Comment: You run it once on the class instance and once on the class. Why do you expect similar results?

Comment: This clearly doesn't look the same `self` is instance of `Window`, and `Window` itself is a `Class`. Could you show us more code? especially what Window is and where is `dir(self)` initialized.

Comment: Change `self` to `type(self)` and the result will be the same. Class is a class, self is an instance of that class. Instance has all the things you set as `self.something = `, class does not have those.

Comment: I see. So how do I go about getting the checkbox values from outside the class? Can I dir the class instance from outside the class?

Comment: Yes, you can `dir` the class instance from outside the class. Look at my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class such as `Window` is not instantiated. Therefore it can't access anything that requires a class instance. In the following code:

```
class A:
    b = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

print(dir(A))
inst = A()
print(dir(inst))
```

`dir(A)` will not contain `a`, because access to `a` requires instantiation as it is declared individually for each instance in the `__init__` method. It will contain `b`, which is static (belongs to the class itself and not its instances). `dir(inst)` will contain both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks. What if my constructor has a parent too? I'm not sure what required positional argument to give in this case.

class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):
 def __init__( self, parent ):
wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Multi Server Tool", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 1280,720 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.MAXIMIZE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. Had to give None along with it